# Vehicle skills using or-tools with C#

Tags: c#, traveling-salesman, or-tools, vehicle-routing

Im trying to solve [Vehicle Routing with Pickups and Deliveries](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/pickup_delivery) using or-tool with C#. Is it possible to add some kind of skills (product type) to the vehicle?
example:

- vehicle1 - skills [liquid]
- vehicle2 - skills [liquid, gas]
- vehicle3 - skills [solid]
- pickup1 - type [gas]
- pickup2 - type [liquid]

So pickup1 can only be picked up by vehicle2, but pickup2 can be picked up by vehicle1 or vehicle2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the vehicle var of each node to filter unskilled vehicles.

For a given node, the vehicle var has a domain `[-1, 0, .., num_vehicle - 1]`.

`-1` is assigned to the vehicle var if the node is not visited.

So if you have `n` vehicle, and you want to forbid vehicle `i` to visit node `j`, you need to remove i from the domain of the vehicle var `j`.

After this removal, the domain of the vehicle var should be `[0, .., i - 1, i + 1, .. , n - 1]` if the node is not optional, or `[-1, .., i - 1, i + 1, .. , n - 1]` if the node is optional.

Comment: could you explain that `-1` thing one more time please? I didn't get it.